# No matching distribution found for PySide2

Tags: pyside2

I get this error when trying to install PySide2 from the Mac's Terminal:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySide2
```

I checked to make sure I have only 1 installation of Python on my MacBook. The screen shot shows the commands I used to check where Python is located and the recommended command I've seen online. I also have the latest version of pip and Python installed. I need PySide2 for PySimpleGUIQt. I also tried home brew, but it also couldn't locate PySide2, but found something called PySide@2 which I don't know if that's another name for PySide2.

[image]

Comment: Are you on apple silicon (M1)? If that's so, there's no wheels available for PySide2, so you either use mac ports, build from sources, or switch to PySide6.

Comment: Yes. It's that version. I believe  PySimpleGUIQt requires PySide2. Can you tell me how to do it with Mac ports?

Comment: No, I can't. Look for some tutorials and how-to's on the project website and qt forum.

Comment: After some more research, I found out that PySide2 is not supported for M1 Macs any more so I installed PySide6 which I found out is supported. When I ran my Python app PySimpleGUIQt still gave me the error message indicating it needed PySide2. Now I need to find out if anyone knows of any way to get PySimpleGUIQt to look for PySide6.

Comment: As already said, you can compile it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

It's cause you have python newest then pyside2 support. I try to install pyside2 on python 3.10 (3.9 same error) and get this error.

Proof:
[image]

But in 3.8 it's worked (but on Pypi https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/ it's must work and on 3.9 and 3.10)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you show a screen shot of the actual commands and parameters you entered where you were able to install PySide2 successfully? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, pip install pyside2, we can see this at the screen number two.